# Blender 2.8+ Laggy everywhere Mac

Tags: osx

I've installed multiple different versions of 2.8 and also tried 2.9 but the whole application runs at below 20fps when im using it and im not sure why. Id love to transition over to 2.8 and onwards but working and modelling with a frame rate below 20fps constantly just isnt possible. Im using a base model MacBook Pro 2017 and 2.79 still runs fine, but im not sure what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tested it against 2.79, but I had severe performance issues with 2.8 on a quite new MacBookPro as well. Turned out it was for me the Graphics Chip not able to deal with 2x Retina. I use EasyRes from the App Store to bring it down to 1x